# Pass Variable From Django to Jquery in HTML File

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x, html

I want to pass a string variable from a **django** view to a jQuery statement in an HTML file to set the value of an input field. Example of what I want to do:

**`views.py` file:**

```
def myview(request):
    return render(request, 'my_file.html',context={'var':'name_attr'}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[name=[{{ var }}]').val('some value');
```

What is the correct syntax or process to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative. Assigning the django variable that was passed to a javascript variable within the html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var js_var= "{{ var}}".replace(/&quot;/g,"\"");
    $('input[name="'+js_var+'"]').val('Text I want in input field.');
</script>
```